# SharedPreferences not refreshing?

Tags: android

I'm using sharedPreferences to store some simple data that I access periodically. I've noticed that when I "put" something using the `SharedPreferences.Editor` (I do call `commit()`) when I later try to access the prefs with `prefs.getAll()` my newly added item is not there.

Oddly, if I close my app and fire it up again, it appears. It's like the prefs are not refreshing while my app is running. Is that by design? What gives?

BTW, I've noticed the same behavior while doing `editor.remove("key")`. I remove something (and call `commit()`), and when I call `getAll()` the deleted item is still in the `Map` returned. If I try to delete it again, my app force closes.

I must be doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Bobby

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen if you use SharedPreferences the right way. The only two scenarios I can think of when this happens is if:

1. [commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) returns false (yes, it does really have a return value) or
2. you are trying to use the SharedPreferences across multiple processes, which is [not supported yet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Hello, I have checked the return and it is true. I'm not sure what you mean by "across multiple processes" - I do not think that applies to my app. Again, if I exit my app and get back in, all of my changes are there.

Comment: Then it seems you are doing something wrong at a different place, and you have to provide more code (as LadaRaider already pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my blunder. I was displaying the list of prefs in a freaking dialog. I missed that the dialog create was only called once so it never updated with my new values. Gah!

Thanks anyway!